# Validation android

Tags: android, function, validation

I'm new in android programming but I have a validation function after the user inserts some data like:source point,destination point,...etc
I have 2 spinners :source and destinations ,both include same values..and i want to be able to send a pop up if a user is selecting the same source and destination and the function is this one:
spSursa=is the source spinner
spDestinatie=is the destinations spinner

```
private boolean validare_Date()
{
   if(spSursa.getSelectedItem().toString()!=spDestinatie.getSelectedItem().toString() )
    {
       if(ratb.isChecked()==false && metrorex.isChecked()==false && both.isChecked()==false)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.ADAUGA_RUTA_EROARE_TRANSPORT, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.ADAUGA_RUTA_EROARE_SURSA_DEST, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code formatting is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
if(spSursa.getSelectedItem().toString()!=spDestinatie.getSelectedItem().toString() )
```

To

```
if(!spSursa.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(spDestinatie.getSelectedItem().toString()))
```

Comment: THANKS,that was the problem.

Comment: @RamonaAndreea happy to help you